# Error messages for FindRoot and NIntegrate

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I want to solve the following problem.

First, the setup. A function $V(\varphi)$ defined as
\begin{multline}
 V(\varphi)=\frac{\alpha-3}{4}e^{\sqrt{2\alpha}\varphi}+\frac{\alpha-5}    {\gamma}e^{(\alpha-1)\sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\varphi}+\frac{\alpha^2-    7\alpha+4}{\alpha\gamma^2}e^{(\alpha-2)\sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\varphi}-\\
        -\frac{\alpha(\gamma+2)^2}{4\gamma^2}+\frac{(\gamma+2)(3\gamma+14)}    {4\gamma^2}-\frac{4}{\alpha\gamma^2}~,
\end{multline}
where $\varphi$ is a real variable and $\alpha$ is a constant real parameter (specifically I'm interested in $\alpha>(7+\sqrt{33})/2$). $\gamma$ is just $\gamma=2(2-\alpha)/\alpha$.

Then, there is the integral: 
$$N_e=\int^{\varphi_i}_{\varphi_f} d \varphi\frac{V(\varphi)}{V'(\varphi)},$$
where $\varphi_i$ is defined as
$$\varphi_i=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\ln\left(\frac{\alpha^2-7\alpha+4}{(\alpha-3)(\alpha-2)}\right)~,$$
and is negative for $\alpha>(7+\sqrt{33})/2$, while $\varphi_f$ is the (negative) root of the equation
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{V'(\varphi)}{V(\varphi)}\right)^2=1~.$$

My goal is to find the value of $\alpha$ for which $N_e=50$.

My attempt:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

V[φ_, α_] := ((α - 3)/4)*E^(Sqrt[2*α]*φ) + 
    ((α - 5)/γ)*E^((α - 1)*Sqrt[2/α]*φ) + ((α^2 - 7*α + 4)/(α*γ^2))*
     E^((α - 2)*Sqrt[2/α]*φ) - (α*(γ + 2)^2)/(4*γ^2) + 
    ((γ + 2)*(3*γ + 14))/(4*γ^2) - 4/(α*γ^2); 

γ = (-2*(α - 2))/α; 

ϵ[φ_, α_] := (1/2)*(D[V[φ, α], φ]/V[φ, α])^2; 

φi[α_] := Sqrt[α/2]*Log[(α^2 - 7*α + 4)/((α - 3)*(α - 2))]; 

φf[α_] := φ /. FindRoot[ϵ[φ, α] == 1, {φ, -0.3}]; 

Ne[(α_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[V[φ, α]/D[V[φ, α], φ], {φ, φf[α], φi[α]}];

FindRoot[Ne[α] == 50, {α, 11}]
```

However, this gives a list of errors most of which are on NIntegrate. For example the first two are

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in φ near {φ} = {-0.748946837826036636752475288418998372825970122595301559087488385558}. NIntegrate obtained 25.416144461679007` and 2.053555362055963` for the integral and error estimates.
```

And the last one on FindRoot:

```
FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
```

I'm not sure how to improve my code. Desirable accuracy for $\alpha$ would be two digits after the decimal point.

**Updated the code.**

Comment: Please check the definition of  `\[Epsilon][\[Alpha]_]=...` (rigth hand side only depends on  `\[CurlyPhi]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Should I define it as \[Epsilon][\[Alpha]_,\[CurlyPhi]] ? Because V contains $\alpha$ as a parameter. Or should I define V[\[CurlyPhi]_,\[Alpha]] too?

Comment: @ Kosm I think you should define both functions depending on `\[CurlyPhi]_, \[Alpha]_` !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Updated my code.

Comment: @ Kosm: Reflecting about your problem, are you sure about the integrand `V/V'`. What about `V'/v`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The integrand is correct, V/V'. I'll try your answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your integrand has a simple pole at `φi[α]` and therefore does not converge.

First fix up your definitions.  If you want `γ` defined outside of `V[]`, define it with complete arguments `γ[α_] :=...`.

```
V[φ_, α_] := With[{γ = (-2*(α - 2))/α},
   ((α - 3)/4)*E^(Sqrt[2*α]*φ)
     + ((α - 5)/γ)*E^((α - 1)*Sqrt[2/α]*φ)
     + ((α^2 - 7*α + 4)/(α*γ^2))*E^((α - 2)*Sqrt[2/α]*φ)
     - (α*(γ + 2)^2)/(4*γ^2)
     + ((γ + 2)*(3*γ + 14))/(4*γ^2)
     - 4/(α*γ^2)
   ];

ϵ[φ_, α_] := (1/2)*(D[V[φ, α], φ]/V[φ, α])^2;
```

Here we can see that the integrand has a pole if the coefficient does not vanish (which it does not seem to do):

```
Assuming[α > 0,
 Simplify@ SeriesCoefficient[V[φ, α]/D[V[φ, α], φ], {φ, φi[α], -1}]
 ]
(*
(12 - α^3 - 
 12 ((4 - 7 α + α^2)/(6 - 5 α + α^2))^-α + α^2 (7 - 
    3 ((4 - 7 α + α^2)/(6 - 5 α + α^2))^-α) + α (-16 + 
    21 ((4 - 7 α + α^2)/(6 - 5 α + α^2))^-α))/((-2 + α)^2 (-3 - 2 α + α^2))
*)
```

Comment: I suppose that the pole with the largest value of $\alpha$ is at $\alpha=(7+\sqrt{33})/2$. Since I'm interested in $\alpha$ greater than this value, should I add the assumption $\alpha>(7+\sqrt{33})/2$ to NIntegrate?

Comment: @Kosm You have the pole at  `φ == φi[α]` as a limit of integration in `NIntegrate`.  I don't see how the assumption helps with the computation. Besides, `NIntegrate` never sees the variable `α` because a numeric value is always substituted for. (If the interval of integration contained both sides of the pole, you could use the principal value; if it did not contain the pole, the integral would converge. Aside from there being some such error in the setup of the integral, there's nothing I can suggest at present.)

Comment: @Kosm I see you've put a bounty on the question. The answer "the integral does not converge" (that is, it diverges) is a complete mathematical answer. One might say it this way in this case, "the integral goes to infinity for all `α`." This lack of mathematical convergence is a distinct concept from the lack of numerical convergence reported by `NIntegrate[]`, although mathematical divergence implies numerical divergence. In other words, if the answer cannot be infinity for other reasons, then the integral has been formulated incorrectly.

Comment: I see. I guess I can shift the $\varphi_i$ by a small amount away from the pole then.

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution approach:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
\[Gamma] = (-2*(\[Alpha] - 2))/\[Alpha];
V[\[CurlyPhi]_, \[Alpha]_] := ((\[Alpha] - 3)/4)*E^(Sqrt[2*\[Alpha]]*\[CurlyPhi]) + ((\[Alpha] - 5)/\[Gamma])*E^((\[Alpha] - 1)*Sqrt[2/\[Alpha]]*\[CurlyPhi]) + ((\[Alpha]^2 - 7*\[Alpha] +4)/(\[Alpha]*\[Gamma]^2))*E^((\[Alpha] - 2)*Sqrt[2/\[Alpha]]*\[CurlyPhi]) - (\[Alpha]*(\[Gamma] +2)^2)/(4*\[Gamma]^2) + ((\[Gamma] + 2)*(3*\[Gamma] +14))/(4*\[Gamma]^2) - 4/(\[Alpha]*\[Gamma]^2);
\[CurlyPhi]i[\[Alpha]_] :=Sqrt[\[Alpha]/2]*Log[(\[Alpha]^2 - 7*\[Alpha] + 4)/((\[Alpha] - 3)*(\[Alpha] - 2))];
\[Epsilon][\[CurlyPhi]_?NumericQ, \[Alpha]_?NumericQ] := (1/2)(Derivative[1, 0][V][\[CurlyPhi], \[Alpha]]/V[\[CurlyPhi], \[Alpha]])^2;
```

The solution `\[CurlyPhi]f[\[Alpha]]` doesn't work in the final evaluation, taht 's why I try to find a good approximation

```
cplot = ContourPlot[\[Epsilon][\[CurlyPhi], \[Alpha]] ==1, {\[Alpha], (7 + Sqrt[33])/2., (7 + Sqrt[33])/2. +Pi}, {\[CurlyPhi], -Pi/2, -.010}, FrameLabel -> {\[Alpha], \[CurlyPhi]}];
\[Alpha]\[CurlyPhi] = cplot[[1, 1]]; (*plotpoints*)
\[CurlyPhi]f[\[Alpha]_] := Fit[\[Alpha]\[CurlyPhi], {1, \[Alpha], \[Alpha]^2},\[Alpha]] //Evaluate
Show[{cplot,Plot[\[CurlyPhi]f[\[Alpha]], {\[Alpha], 6, 10},PlotStyle ->{Opacity[.1], Thickness[.02], Red}]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 0}]
```

[image]

Now it's possible to define function `Ne[\[Alpha]]`.

```
Ne[(\[Alpha]_)?NumericQ] := Evaluate@Apply[NIntegrate, {V[\[CurlyPhi], \[Alpha]]/Derivative[1, 0][V][\[CurlyPhi],\[Alpha]], {\[CurlyPhi],\[CurlyPhi]f[\[Alpha]], \[CurlyPhi]i[\[Alpha]]}}];

Plot[Ne[\[Alpha]], {\[Alpha], 6.5, 15}, Evaluated -> True,PlotRange -> {0, 100} ,GridLines -> {{11}, {50}}, MaxRecursion -> 3,AxesLabel -> {\[Alpha], Ne[\[Alpha]]}]
```

[image]

FindRoot doesn't solve the equation  `Ne[\[Alpha]] == 50` but

```
NMinimize[{1,Ne[\[Alpha]] == 50, \[Alpha] > (7 + Sqrt[33])/2}, \[Alpha]]
(*{1., {\[Alpha] -> 10.8255}}*)
```

does!

Comment: This is strange. It gives me again a list of errors starting with "NIntegrate::nlim: \[CurlyPhi] = -1.10127+0.0972841 \[Alpha]-0.00359968 \[Alpha]^2 is not a valid limit of integration."

Comment: NMinimize gives this: NMinimize::nosat: Obtained solution does not satisfy the following constraints within Tolerance -> 0.001`: {50-Ne[\[Alpha]]==0}.

Comment: It still solves NMinimize, but on my machine it is "\[Alpha] -> 11.17"

Comment: I edited my answer  `Ne[]` now without message  "valid limit of integration". Convergence problem of `NIntegrate` still remains!

Comment: why do you think the solutions differ for us?

Comment: The plot `Ne[\[Alpha] ]` shows several possible solutions because the curve isn't very smooth due to convergence problems of NIntegrate.

Comment: For dimensional reasons (integration by substitution) I still mistrust the form `V/V' ` of the integrand. Using `V'/V`   as a trial gives a smooth result without convergence problems...

Comment: well, usually one calculates this integral after fixing all the parameters (in my case alpha). My goal was to find restrictions on alpha. The integral $N_e$ stands for the number of e-foldings in inflationary cosmology, so you can look it up.

Comment: The integration limit `\[CurlyPhi]i[\[Alpha]]` give singular values of the integrand. Perhaps you can reduce the convergence problems using `Method-> "PrincipalValue",Exclusions->...` ???

Comment: I will try. Thanks!